# ansible yum not working

Tags: python, ansible, centos7, yum

when i run command on the ops machine:

```
ansible web -b -l 192.168.31.101 -m yum -a "name=gcc state=latest"
```

it returns error shows below:

```
192.168.31.101 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "python2 bindings for rpm are needed for this module. python2 yum module is needed for this  module" 
}
```

but when i execute the command `sudo yum install gcc` directly on `192.168.31.101`, executed properly.

it seems like ansible can't use the right yum and python

Comment: Try using `-m package` instead of `-m yum`. It's supposed to work with various package managers. I think yum is going to get replaced by DNF. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnf_(Fedora). Perhaps the yum python module is no longer installed by default in the latest centos images?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find the solution, just add a python path to hosts file

```
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me because i had python2.7 and python3 installed on my machin. ansible was using python3 and thus the error.
so I had to explicitly specify it like below in my makefile target
`/bin/python2.7 /bin/ansible-playbook configure-box.yml`

Answer (score 0):

In my condition, I need install `yum` package and reconfig virtualenv with flag `--system-site-packages` on target host, then use ansible environment variable `ansible_python_interpreter`.

```sh
yum install yum
virtualenv --system-site-packages venv
```

Comment: You probably mean `pip install yum` ?